# LDA python library not taking sparse matrix as input

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, lda

I am trying to use the [lda 1.0.2 package for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lda).

[The documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/lda/api.html#module-lda.lda) says that sparse matrix are acceptable, but when I pass a sparse matrix to the `transform()` function. It throws the error

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   Use a.any() or a.all().

The `transform()` function works fine with normal matrix.

Has anybody else faced similar problem ?

any help will be great! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail please? The full stack trace of the error may be helpful, as might the code near the point where the exception is occuring.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help the community provide the best answer possible, please provide the full text of the error that you are receiving, and please provide concise code that can reproduce the error. Take a look at [this section of the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on how to get the most out of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error. To reproduce:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import lda

X = csr_matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])
lda_test = lda.LDA(n_topics=2, n_iter=10)
lda_test.fit(X)
X_trans = lda_test.transform(X)
```

Which produces the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-a1a0875bac02> in <module>()
      5 lda_test = lda.LDA(n_topics=2, n_iter=10)
      6 lda_test.fit(X)
----> 7 X_trans = lda_test.transform(X)

C:\Users\lidw6lw\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\lda\lda.pyc in transform(self, X, max_iter, tol)
    173         n_topics = len(self.components_)
    174         doc_topic = np.empty((len(X), n_topics))
--> 175         WS, DS = lda.utils.matrix_to_lists(X)
    176         # TODO: this loop is parallelizable
    177         for d in range(len(X)):

C:\Users\lidw6lw\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\lda\utils.pyc in matrix_to_lists(doc_word)
     44     if np.count_nonzero(doc_word.sum(axis=1)) != doc_word.shape[0]:
     45         logger.warning("all zero row in document-term matrix found")
---> 46     if np.count_nonzero(doc_word.sum(axis=0)) != doc_word.shape[1]:
     47         logger.warning("all zero column in document-term matrix found")
     48     sparse = True

C:\Users\lidw6lw\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.pyc in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     23 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
     24     return um.add.reduce(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
---> 25                             out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
     26 
     27 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

C:\Users\lidw6lw\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.pyc in __bool__(self)
    181             return True if self.nnz == 1 else False
    182         else:
--> 183             raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
    184                              "element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().")
    185     __nonzero__ = __bool__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

Looks like it's due to `lda.utils.matrix_to_lists`

Both of the below work just fine:

```
X_trans = lda_test.fit(X.toarray())
X_trans2 = lda_test.fit_transform(X)
```

EDIT: It's actually that the transform function that doesn't account for sparse matrices properly.Make a copy of the package, and in the code for `transform`just replace `len(X)` with `X.shape(0)` and comment out the `np.atleast_2d(X)` line. So the section right below the docstring in `transform` looks like this:

```
# X = np.atleast_2d(X)
phi = self.components_
alpha = self.alpha
# for debugging, let's not worry about the documents
n_topics = len(self.components_)
doc_topic = np.empty((X.shape[0], n_topics))
WS, DS = lda.utils.matrix_to_lists(X)
# TODO: this loop is parallelizable
for d in range(X.shape[0]):
```

Comment: The error is generated by transform but no fit or fit_transform. In the real training and test, it's not acceptable to fit your test set into the model.

Comment: Fixed in newer versions, so no need to modify: https://github.com/ariddell/lda/commit/d44e73ccce8aa6b175811fa5e176ca82a07ab8e7#diff-14db5320aced81aaa087dee133ddf68f

Answer (score 0):

Got the similar error recently.

```
ValueError: expected sparse matrix with integer values, found float values
```

This fixed the issue:

`model.fit(X.toarray().astype(int))`